# tzinfo-data + Rails is reporting the wrong timezone offset for ireland

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tzinfo

I am seeing some strange results whilst trying to retrieve the time zone for Ireland.

On Mac OS X (without tzinfo-data)

```
include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper
time_zone_options_for_select.split.select { |opt| opt =~ /Dublin/ }

=> ["value=\"Dublin\">(GMT+00:00)", "Dublin</option>"]
```

Then on Ubuntu I get:

```
=> ["value=\"Dublin\">(GMT+01:00)", "Dublin</option>"]
```

Then, on Mac OS X with 'tzinfo-data' I get:

```
=> ["value=\"Dublin\">(GMT+01:00)", "Dublin</option>"]
```

Ireland is GMT+0 (the offsets don't include DST, London is currently report +0 and Madrid +1, but as I write both as those are using +1 and +2 (BST and CEST))

Why am I getting GMT+1 on Ubuntu or with tzinfo-data?

Edit:

Ok, I have some results without rails
Using `tzinfo-data` 1.2018.4

```
> require 'tzinfo/data'
> TZInfo::Timezone.get('Europe/Dublin').current_period.utc_offset
=> 0
```

using `tzinfo-data` 1.2018.5

```
> require 'tzinfo/data'
> TZInfo::Timezone.get('Europe/Dublin').current_period.utc_offset
=> 3600
```

Comment: The offsets should indeed include DST. You can try it by using for example by using the [timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to simulate another date and then looking up the timezone information again.

Comment: But I don't see timezone offsets for other areas. For example:

    > time_zone_options_for_select.split.select { |opt| opt =~ /London|Madrid|Paris/ }
    => ["value=\"London\">(GMT+00:00)", "London</option>",
     "value=\"Madrid\">(GMT+01:00)", "Madrid</option>",
     "value=\"Paris\">(GMT+01:00)", "Paris</option>"]

The actual offset in use in those places are +1, +2 and +2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. It turns out the Ireland actually uses a negative offset in winter, not a positive offset in summer (it's currently the only country in the world to do this).

The latest IANA timezone release 2018f correctly uses a negative offset for Ireland, while earlier (released) versions were using a different base timezone and a positive offset during summer.

Comment: THANK YOU. I thought I was going crazy today with the differences between running tests on my mac locally and on my ubuntu server in prod.